# JavaScript - how can I add support for multiple events in "on" function?

Tags: javascript

I have made a simple JavaScript library with a `on` function.
The library works fine but I want to get my `on` function to support multiple events and add events to all the elements.

What is the most efficient way I can do this?

Here is the code for my `on` function:

```
Q.fn.on = function(type, fn){
  this[0]["on" + type] = fn;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were only adding events to the first element because you were using `this[0]`.
`this[0]` is the first item in the `this` object I.E the first element.
What you want to do is loop through **ALL** the elements in the `this` object and add an event listener to each element.

To support multiple events you want to split your "type" string (now called `events`) into an array, loop through that array and attach each element with the each event in that array.

This should work for what you are trying to achieve.

```
Q.fn.on = function(events, callback) {
  // split multiple events into an array
  // or push a single event into a new array
  events = events.match(" ") ? events.split(" ") : [events];
  // loop through the events
  for(var e = 0; e < events.length; e++) {
    // replace the "on" in the event, we don't need it.
    ev = events[e].replace(/^on/, "");
    // loop through your elements, you want to add an event listener to all of them
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      // add your event listener to the element
      this[i].addEventListener(ev, callback, false);
    }
  }
};
```

Just in case you need a `off` function that behaves in the same way:

```
Q.fn.off = function(events, callback) {
  // split multiple events into an array
  // or push a single event into a new array
  events = events.match(" ") ? events.split(" ") : [events];
  // loop through the events
  for(var e = 0; e < events.length; e++) {
    // replace the "on" in the event, we don't need it.
    ev = events[e].replace(/^on/, "");
    // loop through your elements, you want to remove the event listener from all of them
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      // remove your event listener from the element
      this[i].removeEventListener(ev, callback, false);
    }
  }
};
```

For more information on adding and removing events in JavaScript visit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".el").on({
  click: function() {
    // Do something
  },
  mouseenter: function() {  
    // Do something  
  },
  mouseleave: function() {  
    // Do something
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for help but I'm not using jQuery or other librarys.